# d3 - may I somehow compose two projections, or project a projection?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, mapping, projection, composition

I would like to create a map which has been tilted back on the Z-axis, as if you were looking at it laid flat on a table.  No problem: use Mike Bostock's [custom projection](https://gist.github.com/mbostock/5663666) approach, define a simple transformation that scales back as it goes towards the top, call it a day.

Except in the process I learned that d3 was defaulting to the Albers USA projection, and that using my custom projection put Alaska and Hawaii back to their correct placements (which I don't want.)

Also, I hadn't realized Puerto Rico wasn't on the Albers USA projection, so I'd actually like to switch to [Albers USA + PR](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5629120).

I would prefer not to remake the projection if I can help it, because someday I'll find an Albers that also has the various other US territories.

Are projections composable somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing the exact details of your implemenation I have [forked](http://bl.ocks.org/altocumulus/7b45f0db15153f52a2fcfb927f53835f) Mike Bostock's Block [*AlbersUSA + PR*](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5629120) to show a way this could be done.

At its core this uses the Albers USA projection which includes Puerto Rico as requested. This is a normal [D3 projection](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Projections):

```
var albersUsaPrProj = albersUsaPr()
    .scale(1070)
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);
```

Next, I have implemented a rather naïve projection to the table which might need some refinement, but should be enough to get you started. This one uses [`d3.geo.transform()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Streams#transform) to create a stream wrapper for the calculations needed to project the map on the desktop. The wrapped [stream listener](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Streams#stream-listeners) needs to implement just the `point` method that will be called with the `x`, `y` screen coordinates which are the results from the geo projection.

```
// The scale is used for convenient calculations only.
var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
               .domain([0,height])
               .range([0.25,1]);

var desktopProj = d3.geo.transform({
  point: function(x,y) {
    this.stream.point((x - 0.5*width) * yScale(y) + (0.5*width), y);
  }
});
```

Both projections are easily combined into one new stream wrapper by creating an object implementing the `.stream()` method.

```
var combinedProj = {
  stream: function(s) {
      return albersUsaPrProj.stream(desktopProj.stream(s));
  }
};
```

According to the documentation on [`projection.stream(listener)`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Projections#stream):

> Returns a projecting stream wrapper for the specified listener. Any geometry streamed to the wrapper is projected before being streamed to the wrapped listener.

This will first let `albersUsaPrProj` take care of the map's Albers USA projection and, afterwards, stream the resulting screen coordinates to `desktopProj`.

This combined projection may then be passed to [`path.projection([projection])`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Paths#path_projection):

> For more control over the stream transformation, the *projection* may be specified as an object that implements the *stream* method. (See example.) The stream method takes an output stream as input, and returns a wrapped stream that projects the input geometry; in other words, it implements [projection.stream](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Projections#stream).

This give us the final call as

```
var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(combinedProj);
```

Comment: Delightful. I believe that this is exactly what I need.  SO is making me wait an hour to award the bounty.

Comment: Incidentally: do you know of a phrasing for some variant similar to Albers + PR that includes all US territories, or is +PR the best I'm gonna get, and I'll have to move the others myself?

Comment: @JohnHaugeland I am not sure what other US territories you would need to move yourself when using Albers US + PR as this projection will conveniently depict the mainland US, Alaska, Hawaii, and Puerto Rico. If I am not completely mistaken, that should pretty much include the territories claimed by the US ;-)

Comment: Guam, the Mariana Islands, American Samoa, and the US Virgin Islands are missing.  There are ten uninhabited areas (eg the Palmyra Atoll) which could also be added.  If you need to cover COFA territories, then you also need to cover the countries The Phillipines, Micronesia, Palau, and the Marshall Islands.

Comment: That is to say, the seats of four congresspeople are missing.

Comment: Ok, looks like we both learned a lesson from this question ;-) Unfortunately, this is beyond my knowledge.

Comment: Maybe something like [*United States of America with Territories*](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.11.0/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/mapdata/countries/us/custom/us-all-territories) from [here](http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/).

Comment: I mean, except that that's highcharts